# Unknown Angular Watcher

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am a Salesforce developer just getting into AngularJS. 
My question is regarding this piece of code: [Unknown watcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZXX0.png). 
Im using a great snippet to find the watchers in context to the selected DOM Element: 
 (I had to remove this link as I couldnt post more than 2 links)

If you see the highlighted **'tr'** in the console, it has 3 associated Watchers, however the **'tr'** only has a single Angular expression associated with it -> showTheRow(), while all the other expressions are one-way bound using the '::' operator. Why is this happening? Am I missing out on something?

Here is the code snippet:

```
<tr ng-repeat="acc in ::setting_Records.dataWrapperMap['Dealer'] track by acc.account.Id" ng-show="showTheRow(acc.account)" class="dealerRow">
    <td class="filterable-cell">{{::acc.account.Name}} - {{::acc.account.Location__c}} - {{::acc.account.Unit_Name__c}}</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell" ng-class="::acc.pastCompVisits.indexOf('0') == 0 ? 'redClass' : 'greenClass' ">{{::acc.pastCompVisits}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="set in ::acc.dayMon track by set.customerID+set.dayNumber" ng-class="::set.typeCol" class="filterable-cell">
        <div class="multipleEvents" ng-if="::(set.eventList.length > 1)">
            <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MultiUser_Icon)}" styleClass="multiUserIcon" html-ng-click="showPopup(set)"/>
            <div class="eventDetailTooltipStyle" ng-show="evaluatePopup(set)">
                    <div ng-repeat="event in ::set.eventList track by event.event.Id">
                      <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{::$index + 1}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Time:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{::event.event["StartDateTime"] | date: "hh a"}} - {{::event.event["EndDateTime"] | date: "hh a"}}
                            </td>
                            <td ng-if="($index == 0)" align="right" ng-click="closePopup(set)">
                              Close
                            </td>
                            <td ng-if="($index != 0)">                                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Subject:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{::event.event["Subject"]}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Contact Person:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{::event.event["Who"]["Name"]}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td once-style="{'background-color': SAColourMapping[event.event['Owner']['Name']]}" style="border-top-left-radius: 4px;border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;">
                                Assigned To:
                            </td>
                            <td once-style="{'background-color': SAColourMapping[event.event['Owner']['Name']]}" style="border-top-right-radius: 4px;border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;">
                                {{::event.event["Owner"]["Name"]}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-top: 7px;">     
                              <div class="round" ng-if="event.event.OwnerId == scopedUser.Id">
                                      <input type="checkbox" once-id="acc.account.Id + '-' +  'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber + '-' + event.event.Id" ng-disabled="::(set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt)" ng-checked="true"/>
                                        <label ng-attr-for="{{::(acc.account.Id + '-' + 'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber + '-' + event.event.Id)}}" once-style="{'background-color': SAColourMapping[(event.event.Owner.Name)]}" ng-class="::{'disabledCheckboxClass': set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt, 'enabledCheckboxClass' : set.typeCol != 'Holiday' && !set.readOnlySt}" ></label>
                                        <span class="ahevent" ng-if="::(!event.event.WhatId.startsWith('a02'))">AH</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="round" ng-if="event.event.OwnerId != scopedUser.Id">
                                        <input type="checkbox" once-id="acc.account.Id + '-' +  'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber + '-' + event.event.Id" ng-disabled="::(set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt)" ng-checked="false"/>
                                          <label ng-attr-for="{{::(acc.account.Id + '-' + 'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber + '-' + event.event.Id)}}" once-style="{'background-color': SAColourMapping[(event.event.Owner.Name)]}" ng-class="::{'disabledCheckboxClass': set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt, 'enabledCheckboxClass' : set.typeCol != 'Holiday' && !set.readOnlySt}"></label>
                                          <span class="ahevent" ng-if="::(!event.event.WhatId.startsWith('a02'))">AH</span>
                                  </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="round" ng-class="::{'adjustCheckboxClass': set.dayNumber >=1 && set.dayNumber <= 9, '' : set.dayNumber <1 || set.dayNumber > 9}" ng-if="::(set.eventList.length == 1 && set.eventList[0].event.OwnerId == scopedUser.Id)">
            <input type="checkbox" once-id="acc.account.Id + '-' + 'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber" ng-disabled="::(set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt)" ng-checked="true" />
              <label ng-attr-for="{{::(acc.account.Id + '-' + 'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber)}}" once-style="{'background-color': SAColourMapping[(set.eventList[0].event.Owner.Name)]}" ng-class="::{'disabledCheckboxClass': set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt, 'enabledCheckboxClass' : set.typeCol != 'Holiday' && !set.readOnlySt}" ></label>
              <span class="ahevent" ng-if="::(!set.eventList[0].event.WhatId.startsWith('a02'))">AH</span>
        </div>
        <div class="round" ng-class="::{'adjustCheckboxClass': set.dayNumber >=1 && set.dayNumber <= 9, '' : set.dayNumber <1 || set.dayNumber > 9}" ng-if="::(set.eventList.length == 1 && set.eventList[0].event.OwnerId != scopedUser.Id)">
            <input type="checkbox" once-id="acc.account.Id + '-' + 'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber" ng-disabled="::(set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt)" ng-checked="false" />
              <label ng-attr-for="{{::(acc.account.Id + '-' + 'colouredcheckbox-' + set.dayNumber)}}" once-style="{'background-color': SAColourMapping[(set.eventList[0].event.Owner.Name)]}" ng-class="::{'disabledCheckboxClass': set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt, 'enabledCheckboxClass' : set.typeCol != 'Holiday' && !set.readOnlySt}"></label>
              <span class="ahevent" ng-if="::(!set.eventList[0].event.WhatId.startsWith('a02'))">AH</span>
        </div>
        <div class="round" ng-class="::{'adjustCheckboxClass': set.dayNumber >=1 && set.dayNumber <= 9, '' : set.dayNumber <1 || set.dayNumber > 9}" ng-if="::(set.eventList.length == 0)">
            <input type="checkbox" once-id="acc.account.Id + '-' + 'greycheckbox-' + set.dayNumber" ng-disabled="::(set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt)" ng-checked="false" />
              <label ng-attr-for="{{::(acc.account.Id + '-' + 'greycheckbox-' + set.dayNumber)}}" ng-class="::{'disabledCheckboxClass': set.typeCol == 'Holiday' || set.readOnlySt, 'enabledCheckboxClass' : set.typeCol != 'Holiday' && !set.readOnlySt}"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**:

Debugging continues, I came across another Snippet which adds the number of watchers as an attribute to each element: [Watcher probe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYIje.png). This shows the 'tr' element itself has the 2 associated unknown watchers (and not any child element). So, I guess all we have to figure out is why the 'tr' is having those 2 extra watchers.

Comment: Relevant code needs to be included in the question, not via link or image.

Comment: Post the related markup of the repeated `td` element.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response @Brick. Updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response @StanislavKvitash! Updated the question.

Comment: @KanavKhurana but as I can see from the screenshot, there are some `ngIf` inside. Is this reproducible with the markup you've posted?

Comment: Hi @StanislavKvitash. I have updated the question and the snippet. Thanks for your help!